# Multiple CLOSE_WAIT when using google cloud speech api with tornado server. Too many open files error

Tags: python, linux, tornado, google-cloud-speech

I am getting multiple threads of the same process in CLOSE_WAIT because of which i am getting 'too many files open' error.

```
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files:
```

This is happening when multiple calls to google cloud speech api is made.

Have gone through various answers on stackoverflow, but i am unable to figure out the solution.

```
sudo lsof | grep -i close | wc -l

15180
```

The code I have shared is a trimmed version of the actual code. I am able to reproduce the error using the code below.

```
import os
import tornado.httpserver, tornado.ioloop, tornado.options, tornado.web, tornado.escape
import os.path
import string
import json
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import types, enums

tornado.options.parse_command_line()
tornado.options.define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)
SPEECH_TO_TEXT_CREDENTIALS = 'my_json_file.json'
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/home/ubuntu/uploads'

class Application(tornado.web.Application):

    def __init__(self):
        os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = SPEECH_TO_TEXT_CREDENTIALS
        self.speech_client = speech.SpeechClient()
        handlers = [
            (r"/test_bug/client/googlestt2", GoogleSTTHandler)
        ]
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers)

class GoogleSTTHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        if 'audio' not in self.request.files:
            self.finish({'Error': "No audio provided"})
        audio_filename =  'test.wav'
        audio = self.request.files['audio'][0]
        with open(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, audio_filename), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(audio['body'])
        with open(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, audio_filename), 'rb') as audio_file:
            content = audio_file.read()
        audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
        config = types.RecognitionConfig(encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16, language_code='en-IN')
        response = self.application.speech_client.recognize(config, audio)
        if not response.results:
            Transcript_Upload = "Empty Audio"
        else:
            for result in response.results:
                Transcript_Upload = 'Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript)
        self.finish(Transcript_Upload)

def main():
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen(tornado.options.options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Please suggest if I am doing something wrong and how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This known issue in the `google-cloud-python` as well as `gcloud-python` - https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5570.
I dropped it and since then I've been using google API directly.

As side note, you are using synchronous API, but to leverage Tornado (actually any asynchronous framework) you should use async libs/calls etc like [google-cloud-python's Asynchronous Recognition](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/speech/index.html#asynchronous-recognition)